# What screen size should I use for media mobile query?

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, size, media-queries, screen

I have a website I want to fit on a mobile device. I do know that all mobile devices have different screen sizes. what is the best way to go about this?

I also know that you can put **@media** or at **@media screen**

is there a difference between those 2 as well?

Comment: The best way to display a website for mobile is either developing a mobile version strictly for each screen size or a responsive website that will 'expand' when needed automatically.

Comment: if you dont know objective C which is for iOS or whatever android uses look at phonegap, it uses html,css, and javascript only and complies into both android and iOS. phonegap.com

Comment: @innovation The OP isn't asking to create a native app. They simply want to make their website mobile friendly. Thus, no need to learn Objective C or Java (which is what Android uses FYI)

Comment: @RhapX I just offer an alternative example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is by having the divs width measured by percent . like have to divs of 50% each, which will be displayed the same way on any screen . Using percent is the best way. Another way thats much simpler is using bootstrap, which has existing css classes that will help you create responsive divs, images, ect. They have all the right classes that will work for mobile and pc. hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

There are many different practices for building mobile friendly websites. The most notable being [Responsive Web Design](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/layouts/rwd-fundamentals/).

Another method would be to create device specific templates that would need to be coded individually for each devices screen size.

Clearly, the latter of the two is the most labor intensive and can be avoided and used only when working with drastic screen size differences. For instance, you may want to have separate templates for different types of devices instead of screen sizes (phones, tablets, computers).

Doing device specific (not screen size specific) styles allows for better use of space on bigger resolution devices.